# Why one of my IDE HDD isn't showing up while both are detected by BIOS?

Tags: hard-drive

I have 2 hard disks (Western Digital Caviar 30 GB WD300) in my old computer. Both are alone on their IDE channel as master.

When I go in the BIOS, both drives are correctly showing in their respective places. In the POST I see them and SMART is reporting OK for both drives.

But when DOS show up (starting up with a Windows 95 boot disk), only C: is available. What's strange is that C: is the Secondary Master drive.

Both drives have a primary DOS partition (created them with FDISK) and were formatted using FAT32. I managed to format them by only connecting one drive at a time.

The problem is that when both drives are connected at the same time, only one shows up (always the second master one).

I tought it could be a jumper setting so I tried nearly all possibilities (master, cable select, no jumpers...). I also tried to put them both on the same channel in master slave with the same results.

Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Dos guru needed here.

Comment: What do you see when you enter this command: **fdisk /status**?

Comment: @boot13 I see both drives... #2 (Sec Master) as C: The primary master partition isn't detected by FDISK when both drives are connected. If i swap HDDs or if I only connect the PM one, the "missing" partition is shown & works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the HDD was dead finally...